# Enable - Disable addTextChangedListener on EditText through programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

How one can disable `addTextChangedListener` on <kbd>EditText</kbd>?

Scenario:-

I've Four <kbd>EditText</kbd> which used to enter values on which arithmetic operations are done.

<kbd>In Hand</kbd> of
<kbd>%</kbd> -
<kbd>Deducted Amount</kbd> =
<kbd>Amount</kbd>

<kbd>In Hand</kbd>
<kbd>%</kbd>
<kbd>Deducted Amount</kbd> are `Editable` and `addTextChangedListener` is applied.

<kbd>Amount</kbd> : Non Editable

<kbd>In Hand</kbd>
<kbd>%</kbd>
<kbd>Deducted Amount</kbd> have impact on each other.

#### *Impacts:*

If <kbd>In Hand</kbd>
<kbd>%</kbd>
changes :: <kbd>Deducted Amount</kbd>

#### *Problem Area:*

If <kbd>Deducted Amount</kbd> changes :: <kbd>%</kbd> according to <kbd>In Hand</kbd>

But as I've already applied `addTextChangedListener`  on <kbd>%</kbd> which gives psuedo compound action.

Comment: You have the `TextView.removeTextChangedListener(listener)` method for the first question, the rest of your question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
    ...
    boolean changeDeductedAmount = true;
    ...
    //in InHand textChangeListener
    changeDeductedAmount = false;
    editTextDeductedAmount.setText(value);

    //in DeductedAmount textChangeListener
    if (changeDeductedAmount){
       //your code here if user edited text
    } else {
       //edit text was edited by your code, reset flag
       changeDeductedAmount = true;
    }
```

then do this for each pair of Edit text's that can change DeductedAmount